# Ping Request to Virtual Machines Sometimes Drop Sometimes Not

Tags: networking, hyper-v, subdomain, ping, ubuntu-20.04

We have installed on a server PC Hyper-V Server 2019 then install three VMs which are Ubuntu Server 20.04. There are two physical ethernet port on the server PC. We configured one of them as a private NAT switch to share the internet with VMs. This switch is directly connected to internet and it's address 192.168.0.xxx. There is no problem with that one. VMs can connect internet. Second port is configured as external NIC without host's access. It is directly assigned to VMs and VMs addresses in a different subdomain which is 192.168.6.xxx. When we want to ping 0 (subdomain/IP) based devices from VMs it is OK. But when we want to ping VMs from 0 (subdomain/IP) based devices, sometimes all timeout, sometimes complete all requests and sometimes half of the requests timeout half is OK.

What could be the reason of this? Here is the ping output (from Hyper-V host to VMs 2nd (6 based) IPs):

```
C:\> ping 192.168.6.60

Pinging 192.168.6.60 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.6.60: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.6.60: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63

Ping statistics for 192.168.6.60:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 2, Lost = 2 (50% loss).
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\> ping 192.168.6.44

Pinging 192.168.6.60 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.6.60:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss).

C:\> ping 192.168.6.44

Pinging 192.168.6.60 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.6.60: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.6.60: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.6.60:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 2, Lost = 2 (50% loss).
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Thanks.